# Regex for even number only - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, filter, numbers

I have filter in order to only type numbers...Now i want it to only accept even numbers : like 2/4/6/8 but I also wish I could enter 12/32/52/etc... and therefore be able to type the 1*/3*/5*/etc... so **I'm trying to filter only the last character to always have an even number...**

Here is my code :

```js
                    
  function setFilter(textbox, filter) {
    ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
      textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
        if (filter(this.value)) {
          this.oldValue = this.value;
          this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
          this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
        } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
          this.value = this.oldValue;
          this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
        } else {
          this.value = "";
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  function updateInput(){
    //some code

    setFilter(document.getElementById("nbrpages"), function(value) {
        return /^-?\d*((0)|(2)|(4)|(6)|(8))$/.test(value);
     });

      // some code //
    
  }
```

```html
                        <input style="text-align: center; width: 50px; height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);" type="text" id="nbrpages" data-min="60" data-max="100" value="60" oninput="updateInput();"/>
```

**Thanks in advance !**

Comment: can I ask why it must be in regexp and you don't just use `value % 2 === 0` ?

Comment: You could use `type="number"` and the `step` property (as well as `min` and `max` rather than `data-min` and `data-max`): `<input style="text-align: center; width: 50px; height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);" type="number" id="nbrpages" min="60" max="100" value="60" step="2"/>`.

Comment: `/^\d*[02468]$/` can be used for checking even number

Comment: It's not the regex but the logic doesn't make sence, how people going to type `16` without `1` being typed first?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes sorry, data-min and data-max is from my framework, thanks for the type number !

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz the purpose of it, it's when i wanna type 12 i have to type 2 first and then 1 ^^

Comment: Your real problem is in clearing a digit if it's not even. That's really, really annoying. Far better to present a message saying "value must be an even number" and let the user fix it, **don't** automatically delete odd digits.

Comment: @RobG ahah yes i think that's a problem... do you have a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes: "*…Far better to present a message saying "value must be an even number" and let the user fix it*". ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Please make your life simple and just use the modulus here:

```
function updateInput() {
    // some code

    setFilter(document.getElementById("nbrpages"), function(value) {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    });

    // some code
}
```

I'm not an expert in your area of JavaScript, but regex is mainly useful for *textual* comparisons, not arithmetic ones.  To check for divisibility by some number, the modulus (remainder) is much better suited than regex.

Comment: Yes thank you for this proposition, but the purpose of it, it's when i wanna type 12 i have to  type 2 first and then 1 :/
But i agree that modulus is better than a regex for this situation

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the user mad by deleting input I prefer to notify if something is wrong. Here is a jQuery example for letting the user know if the number is not even:

```js
$('#nbrpages').on('input', function (e) {
  let val = $(this).val();
  if(val % 2) {
    $('#nbrpages').addClass('redBorder');
    $('#errmsg').show();
  } else {
    $('#nbrpages').removeClass('redBorder');
    $('#errmsg').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.redBorder {
  border: solid 1px red
}
#errmsg {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="text-align: center; width: 50px; height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);" type="text" id="nbrpages" data-min="60" data-max="100" value="60" /> <span id="errmsg">Only even numbers please</span>
```